# Geting the "pod name" value of a node on Hazelcast with Kubernetes autodiscovery

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, kubernetes-pod, autodiscovery

In a Hazelcast based system, deployed on Kubernetes, using auto-discovery by `service-label`, I'm trying to get the *Pod name* that each node is deployed on. What I'm getting is indeed the pod name for the first node, but the **service name** for the second. For example, `octane-deployment-blue-123c44bfb-xyzab` (pod) and then `10-20-30-100.my-service.svc.cluster.local` (service).

I'm fetching the values by

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = getInstance();
Member localMember = hazelcastInstance.getCluster().getLocalMember();
String name = localMember.getSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostName();
```

It seems that the name is determined by the auto-discovery mechanism.

Any way of getting this value?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer of how to get Pod name is to skip all the Hazelcast part and just get Pod name from the env variable `HOSTAME` or with the use of [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api) like this:

```
env:
- name: MY_POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Saying that, its very weird that you receive service name by executing `localMember.getSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostName()`. Seems like a bug to me. You can raise an issue with the steps to reproduce here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes

Comment: Thanks. That's indeed a way to get the name of the Pod, but I get the pod name of the node through which I send the request to get all node names.